# Unexpected empty key-value in JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to parse a json string embedded in my html file. 
Here is the reduced code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="./jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  function parse_json(){
    var jtext = $("#mtxt").text();
    var jdata = jQuery.parseJSON(jtext);
    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jdata), function (key, value){ 
            alert("key=" + key + " value=" + value);
            if(key== ""){
                    alert("value in string" + JSON.stringify(value));              
            }
    });
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#run").click( function () {
        parse_json();
    }); 
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a id="run" href="#">run</a>
<div id="mtxt">
{"caller": "539293493"}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I parse it, apart from the expected "caller" value, I get an extra empty "key" and "value". 
The first alert gives me

```
key= value=[object Object]
```

The second alert gives me

```
value in string{}
```

What is happening? Why this extra entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you're passing the second param to JSON.parse() which is the `reviver` callback. Per [the JSON docs](http://json.org/js.html), This callback is executed "*...for every key and value at every level of the final result. Each value will be replaced by the result of the reviver function. This can be used to reform generic objects into instances of pseudoclasses, or to transform date strings into Date objects.*"

Since your `reviver` callback doesn't return anything, your object is getting improperly manipulated and distorted. I don't believe you have any use for the `reviver` in your use here.  I have never seen it in use anywhere, and I use `JSON.parse` a LOT.

Your code should look like this:

```
function parse_json()
{
    var jtext = $("#mtxt").text(),
        jdata = JSON.parse( $.trim( jtext ) ),
        key,
        value;

    for( key in jdata )
    {
        if( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( jdata, key ) )
        {
            value = jdata[key];
            //prefer console.log here...
            alert( 'key: ' + key + ', value: ' + value)
        }
    }
}

$( function()
{
    $( '#run' ).click( function()
    {
        parse_json();
    } ); 
} );
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hjVqf/

Comment: I want to iterate over a list of json dicts and I don't know their key values. So I'm forced to use the reviver function. Is there a way around?

Comment: You missed `value= jdata[key]` in your answer. Otherwise it works perfectly.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I had an edit go awry and missed that when fixing it (notice it _was_ in the fiddle). I've corrected it now, thanks.  Glad it works!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've been fooling around with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yScxA/1/) on jsfiddle. One of the things I noticed that you weren't doing, was returning a value for the `reviver` function. According to the Microsoft [JSON.parse docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Y840), the point of the function is to return a modified (if necessary) version of the `value` property which will update the DOM object. Now, it also says that:

> A function that filters and transforms
>   the results. The deserialized object
>   is traversed recursively, and the
>   reviver function is called for each
>   member of the object in post-order
>   (every object is revived after all its
>   members have been revived).

Ok, so I think the key here is that the reason the function is run twice, is because it's running for the first member (simply `"caller": "539293493"`) and then for the object itself  (`{"caller": "539293493"}`).

You'll notice that in my linked example, with the added `return value;` statement, the object with the blank key is the whole object.

Comment: So basically reviver function gets called on Object as well, which is its return value. Why would anybody want that behavior? And whats the workaround ?

Comment: @Neo, the purpose of the behavior is, as I stated in my response, "_used to reform generic objects into instances of pseudoclasses, or to transform date strings into Date objects._"  You do not need this, and the work around is to not use it. Please thoroughly read the responses here (both are spot on--Drackir's got +1 from me) and look at the code and demo I gave you.

Comment: @Neo: The return value of the function is the `value`. In the first run of the function, `value="539293493"`. The second time it's run, `value={"caller": "539293493"}`. If you take a look at the MS docs page I linked to, you'll note that the purpose of the function is to transform the objects within the JSON object, should that be necessary. The function is not for iteration of the object's properties. As for a workaround, @JAAulde has updated his answer with one.